# laravel best way to handle authenticated and not authenticated routes

Tags: laravel

what is the best way to have a route works both with authenticated and not authenticated users?
I explain I need a route that modifies its response in case of authenticated and not authenticated user. now I have a jwt middleware like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use JWTAuth;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Utils\CustomResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException;

class JwtMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function verifyToken(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof TokenInvalidException) {
                return CustomResponse::setFailResponse("invalid token", Response::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
            }else if($e instanceof TokenExpiredException){
                return CustomResponse::setFailResponse("expired token", Response::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
            }else {
                return CustomResponse::setFailResponse("token not found",Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

now this middleware returns the error in case of the wrong token if I apply this to my route it catches and gives a 404 error. do I need another middleware for auth/not auth routes or just not return the setFailResponse and handle it in the routes if it doesn't find the user?

Comment: i think you miss the return statement in try block.

Comment: @sandy if try isok it then  return $next($request); with the user or at least it seems to work in this way now. but my question is another...

Comment: ok, i made another middleware to be applied to the specific routes

Comment: I don't get why you would need a middleware for this. If your route allows unauthenticated requests you will also allow authenticated ones. As the middleware will *not* handle your response. Or do you mean "not authenticated users" = "users that use jwt"?

Comment: Add another route for guest users and do not apply this middleware on it. Then in your controller, you can check if user is authenticated or not by `auth()->check()`.

Comment: ok, thanks for all your answers, sorry, I'm newbie to laravel. I just need a route that sends back some data if an user is authenticated (Authentication token in the headers of the request), or sends other type of data if in the request there is no Authentication token. so you say that i can remove the auth middleware from the route and check inside the controller if there is the token and handle the request